# Is it possible to animate change of UITableViewCell Accessory

Tags: uitableview, uiviewanimation

Very simple situation, multiple rows and only one row should have the checkmark at a time. User selects row X, row X gets checkmark, checkmark removed from previously selected row. But how to animate the change? (Fade in fade out).

I thought maybe this would work:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    previous.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;        
    previous.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;        

}];
```

and also

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

The first did nothing, the second deleted both of the cells referred by the NSIndexPath's in the paths array. I also tried wrapping reloadRowsAtIndexPaths in [tableView beginUpdates/endUpdates].

**UPDATE:**

Calling reloadRowsAtIndexPath on the incoming indexPath (trivial implementation below) is doing the same thing, the row "goes blank".

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

The table is a **static** table, I have properties declared and synthesized for each cell, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns the corresponding cell for each row...

```
.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellNever;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell030;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell100;

.m
@synthesize cellNever;
@synthesize cell030;
@synthesize cell100;
...
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    cells = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cellNever, cell030, cell100, cell130, cell200, cell230, cell300, cell400, cell500, nil];
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I always do `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths...` and it's worked fine for me, not sure why it would delete yours. Are you changing your data, that is to say deleting any data objects, anytime between loading the table and then handling the accessory?

Comment: (Many thanks Carl, you've responded to several of my question!). Please UPDATE above.